# Message Box with link

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to `popup a message box` in a Google Sheet with a text and `clickable hyperlink`.

My searches so far yielded deprecated ui-functions.

Comment: You can use [modal dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function msgBoxWithLink(msg,link,desc) {
  var link=link || 'http://jimesteban.com';
  var desc=desc || 'Description';
  var msg=msg || 'Link';
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<style>input{margin: 5px 0;}</style><h3>%s</h3><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />',msg,link,desc);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Message Box with Link");
}
```

Comment: Hi. when I click the link, it's not clickable, meaning I stay where I was. How can the link be opened (preferably in a new tab/window)?

Comment: I made a change .Try it now.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### UI Service has been depricated, however there several other options to display a message box:

- [msgBox(prompt)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String))
  `Browser.msgBox('hello world');`
  This method is not recommended by https://developers.google.com, but it is not depricated.
- [Alert dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt)
  `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world');`. This is a perfectly [valid method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs).
- [A modal](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface-title) or [modeless dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodelessdialoguserinterface-title), created with help of the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

```
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p>');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
```

Comment: Hi. It creates a link but when I click on it, it's not clickable, meaning I stay where I was. How can the link be opened (preferably in a new tab/window)?