# Formatting the html in a showModelessDialog box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745953/message-box-with-link) I have created the following showModelessDialog box:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YOQSBNEubaglFF5Zng1Oxcm-gAgZIdkUxH13ClozXaU/edit?usp=sharing)

Everything works fine, but I am struggling with the formatting of the popup.  I haven't touched html for 20 years so it's got me bamboozled.

Basically I want to change the paragraph font type to a font called "Teko" and I want to right-align the `Close` button.  The popup box code is as follows:

```
  var html = Utilities.formatString('<style>input{margin: 1px 0;}</style><p>%s<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>%s<br></p><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />',splitMessage[0],link,"check in",splitMessage[1]);
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
                      .setHeight(115)
                      .setWidth(380);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, subject[i]);
```

For the font I have tried `<p font-family: "Teko">` as per [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

As for the button, I've tried `align="right"` in the `<input` field with no luck.

As an aside - if I could remove one of the lines between the heading and the text that would be great!

Comment: You have undefined variable in your example so you didn't provide an [mcve]. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function unk() {
  var html='<style>input{margin: 1px 0;float:right;}p{font-family:"Teko";}</style><p>Message <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"> Link </a> Some Text </p>';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(115).setWidth(380); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper.  The right-align for the button worked.  The font did not.  Upon testing it seems as though it did not recognise the specific font family.  It's an installed font I added to Google Docs.  Interestingly though it didn't recognise "Inconsolata" (which is a base font as far as I know), but it did recognise "Trebuchet MS"

Comment: However I did just realise that Spreadsheet.Ui cannot be called on a Timed Trigger - which was my intention.  The only alternative I'm aware of is toast() - and I do not know if I can add hyperlinks do that.  Can you suggest an alternative popup that will run on a timed trigger and include hyperlinks please?

Comment: Seems as though toast() isn't even an alternative.  I guess there aren't any popups or alerts that activate off timed triggers then?